# Strange behavior with jquery replace in array or "How to replace pieces of a string?"

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, replace

i have to change id value in a form to all input and select field.

```
$(value).find('input, select').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var idArray = id.split("_");
    var newId = id.replace(idArray[5], 2);
        newId = id.replace(idArray[7], (index + 1));
    console.log(newId);
    $(this).attr('id', newId);
});
```

value is the form. the console return the idArray[5] replaced by (index +1)...

Any idea, Thanks

Comment: At least tell us what are you expecting your code to do?!

Comment: sorry, changing the id like "mc_chartbundle_chart_list_yAxis_1_series_1_markerSerie" where idArray 5 and 7 are the numbers in the id.

Comment: You probably want the second time to use `newId`, not `id`: `newId = newid.replace(idArray[7], (index + 1));`. BUT that's still unclear what are you expecting

Comment: I am expecting to have in all serie form, mc_chartbundle_chart_list_yAxis_1_series_1_markerSerie,mc_chartbundle_chart_list_yAxis_1_series_2_markerSerie,mc_chartbundle_chart_list_yAxis_1_series_3_markerSerie...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are calling [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) as your `id` is actually a `string`.
And as second argument you are passing an `int`:

```
var newId = id.replace(idArray[5], 2);
```

This will replace whatever is in that string by the number `2` and not by the second index of your array.

#### Edit

As replacing the parts by numbers is the intended behavior this is what is actually happening:

The replace of `idArray[5]` which equals `1` is replacing the first `1` character it finds with `2`.

The other replace is acting uppon the same origin string (`id` and not `newId`) and replacing the same `1` character to the value of `(index + 1)`.

The solution in this case is to manipulate the array and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it back into a string:

```
$(value).find('input, select').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var idArray = id.split("_");
    idArray[5] = 2;
    idArray[7] = (index + 1);
    var newId = idArray.join('_');
    console.log(newId);
    $(this).attr('id', newId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. in fact, i also try var newId = id.replace(idArray[5], "2"); and i always have the value of (index+1) in idArray[5]. if i remove the replace on idArray[7], nothing happen, the problem come from the replace on idArray[5]

Comment: @maximedumont Edited the answer, see if it fits you better.

Comment: The join solution work fine, i'm now reading the documentation for join. thank you so much Spark. you save my day.